# Does google pay while Admob banner is behind softkeyboard and not visible?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, admob

I couldn't find related information anywhere. When softkeyboards cover my admobbanner can I still get revenue, or is it inactive and no payment when keyboard is opened? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most of the revenue comes, when a user clicks on the ad. Unless your keyboard covers the banner for a long time, it's not a big issue. Otherwise there is not much sense to have the banner, because the user will not see it and won't click on it.